# Легкая задача на js , где ошибка?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка
у меня не работает ничего

Задание по программированию: Добавление интервала ко времени

Условия:

1. На вход функция принимает `3` параметра: часы, минуты, интервал в минутах, на который нужно изменить время.
2. Гарантируется, что любой из `3` параметров целое положительное число.
3. Параметр часы принимает значение в диапазоне `[0, 23]`.
4. Параметр минуты принимает значение в диапазоне `[0, 59]`.
5. Прибавляемый интервал может быть больше `60` минут.
6. Переход в следующие сутки должен корректно обрабатываться.
7. Функция должна возвращать корректно отформатированное время: **1:2 –> 01:02**

```js
module.exports = function (hours, minutes, interval) {
  if ((hours >= 0 && hours <=23) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes <=59)) {
    var newMinutes = (minutes+interval) % 60 ;
    var newHours = (hours + math.floor((minutes+interval) / 60)) % 24 ;
    if ((newHours / 10) < 1 ) {
      newHours = '0' + newHours;
    }
    if ((newMinutes / 10) < 1 ) {
      newMinutes = '0' + newMinutes;
    }
    return `${newHours}:${newMinutes}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: А в чём проблема возникла?

Comment: @suvitruf код не работает вообще. 0 пройденных тестов из 13

Comment: А как вы его вызываете и какие аргументы передаёте? Покажите этот код.

Comment: @Suvitruf **
 * СОБАКАparam {Number} hours
 * СОБАКАparam {Number} minutes
 * СОБАКАparam {Number} interval
 * СОБАКАreturns {String}
 */

Comment: @Suvitruf тесты в олимпиадных и других подобных задачах никогда не показывают, как они работают

Comment: @Анна у вас там как минимум одна ошибка: `math` должно быть с большой буквы => `Math.floor`.

Comment: @Suvitruf спасибо, поправила, но все равно не работает

Comment: @Анна а вы осознанно имя экспортируемой функции не указали или это требование? Обычно указывается что-то вроде `exports.myFunction = function`. Там точно в задании нет пункта на этот счёт?

Comment: @Suvitruf  у нас все задачки с такими функциями, думаю дело именно в коде

Comment: @Анна код то рабочий сам по себе. Я проверил.

Comment: Но поддерживают ли тесты плюшки нового javascript? Может, код надо на каком-нибудь ES3 писать?

Comment: @Suvitruf я делаю задачу на курсера, тут автоматически прогоняют код по тестам. ни одного теста не проходит

Comment: @Suvitruf подскажите, где можно прогонять код?

Answer (score 1):

Как уже говорили в комментариях, код рабочий.

```js
var module = {};
module.exports = function(hours, minutes, interval) {
  if ((hours >= 0 && hours <= 23) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 59)) {
    var newMinutes = (minutes + interval) % 60;
    var newHours = (hours + Math.floor((minutes + interval) / 60)) % 24;
    if (newHours < 10) {
      newHours = '0' + newHours;
    }
    if (newMinutes < 10) {
      newMinutes = '0' + newMinutes;
    }
    return newHours + ':' + newMinutes
  }
}
console.log(module.exports(19, 5, 278));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете также попробовать более красивое решение этой задачи с использованием популярной библиотеки moment.js:

```
const moment = require('moment');


module.exports = function (hours, minutes, interval) {
    return moment().hours(hours).minutes(minutes).add(interval, 'minutes').format('HH:mm');
}
```